# SQL only get rows that matches full number split by a comma

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on something that shows shops under a specific category, however I have an issue because I store the categories of a shop like this in a record with the id of a category. "1,5,12". Now, the problem is if I want to show shops with category 2, it "mistakens" 12 as category 2. This is the SQL right now.

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE shop_cats LIKE '%".$sqlid."%' LIMIT 8
```

Is there a way to split the record "shop_cats" by a comma in SQL, so it checks the full number? The only way I can think of is to get all the shops, and do it with PHP, but I don't like that as it will take too many resources.

Comment: you need to use `IN()` and should have normalized your db. Edit: after seeing @MarkBaker 's comment, that is what I wanted to add in there also.

Comment: You need to test both cases now.. So test whether the shop_cats starts with a `2,` and test if the string is like `,2,`

Comment: Also, this is bad practice in database normalisation. You should have stored them in a seperate table, a pivot table.

Comment: Normalizing your database is the best solution: using MySQL's FIND_IN_SET() function is an inefficient but correct workround

Comment: Use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really, really bad way to store categories, for many reasons:

- You are storing numbers as strings.
- You cannot declare proper foreign key relationships.
- A (normal) column in a table should have only one value.
- SQL has poor string functions.
- The resulting queries cannot take advantage of indexes.

The proper way to store this information in a database is using a junction table, with one row per shop and per category.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  If this is your case, then you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($sqlid, shop_cats) > 0
```

But you should really fix the data structure.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I did think of making it seperate, but at the time it seemed like it would take up more resources (because of more records). Thanks though :)

Comment: By the way, I do have a seperate table for the categories, but I did this as a way of pointing the categories to a shop, do you have another suggestion for doing this?

Comment: @Anders . . . You should use a junction table with one row per shop and per category.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, the correct solution should be to normalize the table, i.e. have a separate row per category, not with commas.

If you can't, this should do the work:

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE CONCAT(',' , shop_cats , ',') LIKE '%,".$sqlid.",%' LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, have a good day. And uhm, for the categories I do have a row for each category in a table called "categories", but I did this as a way of pointing specific categories to a shop. Did I misunderstand you? :p

Answer (score 0):

The table `shops` does not follow 1NF (1st Normal Form) i.e; every column should exactly one value. To avoid that you need to create another table called pivot table which relates two tables (or entities). But to answer your question, the below SQL query should do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE concat(',',shop_cats,',') LIKE '%,".$sqlid.",%' LIMIT 8
```